# Trying to add logging in ASP.NET Core function app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, logging, azure-functions

I am currently working with an ASP.NET Core v6 Function App v4 and want to add logging so I can save the logs to the database.

In past projects I've used Log4Net package, I see there is a nuget package that allows us to use it for ASP.NET Core v6, but it's mostly for web and API projects with `Program.cs` files. The Function App only comes with a `Startup.cs` and doesn't allow you to add `ILogger`.

I am wondering if there is a way or a work around in adding this tool or logging to the project in general or what other options there are our there.

Here is the link to the repo/docs for the nuget package.
[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore)

And the original Log4Net site:

[Log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)

Added like so and get the error:

> IFunctionHostBuilder does not contain a definition of 'Logging' and no accessible extension methedon 'Logging' accepting a first argument of type 'IFunctionsHostbuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using dir or an assembly ref)?

Code:

```
 public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
 {
    //...
    builder.Logging.AddLog4Net();
    //...
 }
```

I'm pretty new to the Function apps so any guidance would be grateful.

Comment: Is this a normal or isolated function app?

Comment: looking in the `local.settings.json` I states for the `FUNCTION_WORKER_RUNTIME: "dotnet"` so guessing its normal.

Comment: Ok. Try looking through this sample: https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.Extensions.Logging/tree/main/samples/Elmah.Io.Extensions.Logging.Function. The `Startup.cs` file contains the logging setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of `Startup.cs` file in favor of one-file `Program.cs`. Configuration is then almost the same as in ASP.NET Core app

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults();

hostBuilder.ConfigureLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.ClearProviders();
    builder.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
});
var host = hostBuilder.Build();

host.Run();
```

Function

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.FunctionApp2;

public  class MyHttpTriggerFunction
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyHttpTriggerFunction> logger;

    public MyHttpTriggerFunction(ILogger<MyHttpTriggerFunction> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    [Function("MyHttpTriggerFunction")]
    public  HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

        response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

        return response;
        
    }
}
```

UPD:
Your csproj file should contain:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

To make app isolated, set configuration value in local.settings.json

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated" <--- this
    }
}
```

and in Azure

[image: Azure]

Comment: It only works this way for isolated function apps, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: when I create the `Program.cs` and add the code I get an error on the `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()` saying `HostBuilder` doesn't contain a definition.

Comment: does it matter if its the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worke` or `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worke.core`

Comment: I don't know the difference between these two

Comment: What is the process in changing the Function App from normal to isolated?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider serilog, will be much more easier to use for non-isolated function. No startup.cs/program.cs or other configuration needed.
Create a project like below.
[image]
Install package `Serilog` ``` Serilog.Sinks.Console``Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer ```
Modify the Function1.cs like below

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {
            var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console(new JsonFormatter())
           .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                        connectionString: "Data Source = 192.168.2.68; Initial Catalog = LogDb; User ID = sa; Password = xxxxx; TrustServerCertificate = True",
                        tableName:"function1_log",
                        autoCreateSqlTable:true               
                 )
            .CreateLogger();

            log.Information("A serilog information");
...
```

Test
[image]
Check Sqlserver
[image]
Reference: https://stackify.com/logging-azure-functions/